# What exactly is a domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If I say for example that the " domain of a function is $\mathbb{R}$ ", then I know that I can expect all $x$ values of this graph to come from the set of real numbers. But is the statement actually saying more than that?

Specifically, does " the domain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$", also force all values of $x$ to yield a defined value of $f(x)$ in the graph?

Comment: Yes, of course. If $f:X\to Y$ is a function then $f(x)$ has to be well defined and in $Y$ for any $x\in X$.

Comment: See [Domain of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function): "In mathematics, the domain or set of departure of a function is the set into which all of the input of the function is constrained to fall." No more than this.

Comment: And see [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)): "In mathematics, a function is a binary relation between two sets that associates every element of the first set to exactly one element of the second set."

Comment: Thank you everyone. Not enough reputation to give some votes here, but I appreciate it. It seems I misunderstood all along. I had thought until now that the domain consists of potential values (even if those ones yield undefined values at spots where the graph had removed that point). I realize now then, that the domain is actually a set of values that indeed to do map to values in the codomain.

Answer (score 2):

A map typically is defined by 3 things:

The domain $A$,  that is a set.
The range $B$,  that is also a set.
The way an element $x$ from $A$ takes a unique value from set $B$.
So answering your question: yes the element $x$ should come from real numbers and as we talk about a function (and not a map) the image should be also real number.

Answer (score -1):

Domain of a function is set of all real numbers where $f(x)$ is real finite and unique.

Domain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-3}$ is $(-\infty, 3) \cup (3, \infty)$.

Domain of $g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is $[-1,1]$.

Domain of $h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is $(-1,1)$

Domain of $k(x)=\sin x, \cos x, e^{x}$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$

Domain of $p(x)=\log x, \sqrt{x}$ is $(0,\infty)$

Domain of $q(x)=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{1-x}$ is $\{1\}.$